# Question about coordinates of the topological maifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I have a fundamental doubt about the manifolds
Let $M$ be a manifold of dimension $n$ so we know that there will be a homeomorphism that is for every $p\in M$ there exists an open set $U\subseteq M$ such that $p\in U$ and a map $\phi: U\subseteq M\to \phi(U)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ which is one-one, onto, continuos and the inverse is also continuous.

Suppose my $M=\mathbb{R^2}$ for which I don't know the coordinates so I defined a homeomorphism map for any $p\in \mathbb{R^2}$, $\phi: U\to \phi(U)$ defined as $\phi(p)=(x+y,x)$, so as the definition says that $\phi(p)=(\phi_{1}(p),\phi_{2}(p))$ will be the coordinates of $M$ so here we will have $(x+y,x)$ as coordinates of $M=\mathbb{R^2}$? I think up to here I am right. But I am not getting an idea of how we are saying the output of the homeomorphic map we have defined will be the coordinates of the manifolds. Please if someone can clarify this doubt that will be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: If $(1,2)\in U$ then its local coordinate would be $(3,2)$. In general, a 2-manifold won't have a set of two dimensional cartesian coordinates that describe the whole space. The idea is that we can find a neighborhood of each point that does.